# Validate input given to SimpleDateFormat new instance

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way( regex or other way) to validate the input given to a new instance of SimpleDateFormat?

e.g. :

```
 String input = getInputFromSomewhere();
 if(validate(input)){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(input);
    //do my job with sdf
 }

boolean validate(String input){
    //what should be here????
}



String input = "yyyy-MM-dd" ; //or any other value which I can't control
String badFormatInput = "NOTHING" ; 

System.out.println(validate(input)) ; //--> true
System.out.println(validate(badFormatInput)); //--> false
```

Comment: What would you want to validate....?

Comment: Some input coming from UI where I do not have control over the way it is build( some user will be building it).

Comment: But it will be Date input (like 2013-01-01), or date pattern input eg.yyyy.MM.dd HH (like you show this in your code)

Comment: The input (which is coming from UI) will represent the parameter given to a new instance of SimpleDateFormat. e.g. : `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: `yyyyyyyyyyy` is a correct format

Comment: Ok , I'll change to another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do dummy parsing to check whether the format is valid

```
boolean validate(String input){
    try {
        new SimpleDateFormat(input).format(new Date());
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be one way yo do that, +1

Comment: @MustafaGenç it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  for any illegal character in format string.. How did u test?

Comment: is leniency relevant here?

Comment: i execute this : `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(".,2.424;;").format(new Date()));`  and it prints `.,2.424;;`

Comment: as it is still valid date format pattern. It does not include date at all, but still, it is valid.

Comment: @MustafaGenç Seems like the SDF ignores the numbers and extra chars in pattern.. Not sure whats the cause, may be a new question to the community.. but if you try `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("NOTHING").format(new Date()));` it fails

Comment: Ahh now I see. Reading a few paragraph here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html explains much. -1 converted to +1. Cheers.

Comment: my vote is locked ffs. it requires answer editing. sorry for this post.

Comment: noprobs, i have edited the post, just incase if you want to rethink the downvote ;)